# Globally installing Laravel/Lumen on Ubuntu

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, installation, lumen

I have an Amazon EC2 instance with Ubuntu 14.4.

I installed my [composer](https://getcomposer.org/download/) globally.

When I install Lumen I get this result - everything seems fine:

```
ubuntu@ip-XXX-XX-XX-XX:/var/www/html$ composer global require "laravel/lumen-installer"
Changed current directory to /home/ubuntu/.config/composer
Using version ^1.0 for laravel/lumen-installer
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Installing symfony/process (v3.1.0)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing symfony/polyfill-mbstring (v1.2.0)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing symfony/console (v3.1.0)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing guzzlehttp/promises (1.2.0)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing psr/http-message (1.0)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing guzzlehttp/psr7 (1.3.0)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing guzzlehttp/guzzle (6.2.0)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing laravel/lumen-installer (v1.0.2)
    Loading from cache

symfony/console suggests installing symfony/event-dispatcher ()
symfony/console suggests installing psr/log (For using the console logger)
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
ubuntu@ip-XXX-XX-XX-XX:/var/www/html$
```

But when I type `lumen` or `lumen new blog` I receive a `lumen: command not found`.

Based on other questions, I assume I have to add lumen to the PATH simillarly to this:

```
export PATH="~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
```

This does not make a difference - `lumen: command not found` is still displayed after running lumen new blog.

Did anyone run into this error?

Comment: Use this instead of above export PATH="$PATH:~/.composer/vendor/bin"

Comment: Worked. Thank you very much :)

Could u pls explain why this worked? Im trying to learn Linux - if u add it as an answer, I will accept the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem will not be solved simply by unsetting PATH, as you'll still be left without a PATH that includes the necessary system directories. When you set your own PATH, in most cases you will want to append your new entry to the old PATH variable, not replace it entirely, as you have done.

Use this command

```
export PATH="$PATH:~/.composer/vendor/bin"
```

Notice the variable is set to begin with the existing $PATH. This way, you'll still have all the original system directories in your PATH, and your addition will be on the end. Because lumen is apparently the name of the binary you are trying to execute, and your PATH should include only directories containing binaries, not the binaries themselves.